# Removing Duplicates in Excel with or without VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

[Chart Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6mGh.png)

Hello All,

I am looking for some help in cleaning up an organizational chart that I have in excel. Right now, there are many duplicates as the linked picture shows. I need to remove all the duplicates, and shift the unique values over into the blank spaces

(i.e., Bill G, Bill G, Fred K, Fred K, Joe X ---> Bill G, Fred K, Joe X).

I have been trying to get it done using Excel Formulas (`=IF(A1=B1, B1, A1)`), but it does not repeat correctly across the Sheet, especially because the different rows have varying numbers of occupied columns.

I'd appreciate any help that I can get. Thank you!

Comment: Copy the cells to a new location with Paste Special, transpose. Remove Duplicates on each column. Copy them back with transpose.

Comment: See [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le).

Answer (score 1):

No need for VBA. Use `Data`, `Advanced filter`, choose `Copy to another location` and check `Unique records only`

Answer (score 1):

Select your range
Go to the Data tab
In the Data Tools pane, select "Remove Duplicates"

Answer (score 0):

> first a formula to bring unique only. the formula display duplicates as `0`.

[image]

> then while still selecting the formula range, open the "go to special" dialog box

[image]

> select Formulas > Numbers

[image]

> all formula output zeros will be selected

[image]

> press `Ctrl + minus(-) to delete cells, select "shift cells left"

[image]

> end result

[image]